# How can I install phpmyadmin using the repository

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have tried the normal way `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` but it always fails. Is there any other way to install **phpmyadmin** from repository.

I got this error,

> Preparing to unpack .../phpmyadmin_4%3a4.0.10-1_all.deb ...
>   Unpacking phpmyadmin (4:4.0.10-1) ...
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
>   Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
>   Processing 1 added doc-base file...
>   Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
>   Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
>   Downloading Oracle Java 6...
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:20--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>   Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.25.108.41, 184.25.108.17
>   Connecting to download.oracle.com 
> (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
>   Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:20--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>   Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.65.97.122, 2600:140f:b:184::2d3e, 2600:140f:b:183::2d3e
>   Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com 
> (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.65.97.122|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
>   Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911 [following]
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:23--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911
>   Connecting to download.oracle.com 
> (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
>   2017-10-25 09:13:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.
>   
>   download failed
>   Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
>   dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You can also use adminer (https://www.adminer.org/) instead of phpmyadmin

Comment: can you paste the command response of installation

Comment: what error did you get? what OS do you use?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Have you installed mysql first ?

Comment: you have mysql installed ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` always fails this could be some missing dependencies. follow the steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

if this fails run

`sudo apt-get install -f`

this command will install the all the missing and required dependencies for previous install command and it will also install the `phpmyadmin` after installing dependencies.